# Using libvlc for multi-format video playback inside an Electron app

Tags: electron, vlc, libvlc

I have an idea for a media player GUI, which I'd like to build using Electron (because it's a tool I know well; I realise it's not for everyone). I could do this easily using an HTML `<video>` element and some custom UI around it, but that would only be able to play a few formats.

I want it to be able to play as many different video formats as possible. So I'm wondering about trying to use [libvlc](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC/).

> The libVLC (VLC SDK) media framework can be embedded into an application to get multimedia capabilities.

I currently know very little about libvlc (or C libraries generally), but I'm hoping it might be possible to interface with it from Node/Electron so I can get it playing a video file inside my Electron GUI.

Before I dive into the libvlc docs, I'd like to know:

- Is what I'm aiming for even possible?
- Are there any existing and maintained open source apps using libvlc for video playback inside their own GUI, that would be good for me to look at?
- On a high level, how does an application actually use libvlc? Does the app make a call to libvlc saying "please play `some/file.mp4` in a video window of X by Y, at these coordinates on the screen", or is it more like "please play `some/file.mp4` and stream me back the decoded video frames so I can render them on my own canvas"?

(BTW there is a project called [node-vlc](https://github.com/tjfontaine/node-vlc) which looked promising but it's unmaintained for over 5 years.)

Comment: https://github.com/RSATom/WebChimera.js but it's abandoned due to some libvlc compatibility issues.

Comment: please share your experience